# Postfix configuration hostname poor format?

Tags: postfix, hostname

Please help. I keep getting "relay host configuration problem." I think this is because I'm not setting up myhostname and mydomain correctly in main.cf. But I don't think my host name will work. I think I'm supposed to insert my machine's host name there, and it is in the format of ip-192-0-2-0.ip.secureserver.net. Can someone help me to figure out if I need to change my hostname or do something else?

Here is the problem from my maillog:

```
Jan 29 14:57:04 ip-192-0-2-0 postfix/smtp[27740]: warning: relayhost configuration problem
Jan 29 14:57:04 ip-192-0-2-0 postfix/smtp[27740]: 6141BB9707F: to=<example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=secureserver.dedrelay.net type=A: Host not found)
```

secureserver.dedrelay.net is GoDaddy's relay mail server, which I'm trying to set up postfix to send mails through. To do this, in main.cf I have:

relayhost = [secureserver.dedrelay.net]:587

Comment: There certainly is no such host as `secureserver.dedrelay.net`. Why is that in there?

Comment: Thank you Michael. Edited question above again to explain.

Comment: There's still no such host. You've gotten invalid information from GoDaddy or somewhere. Ask them to give you the correct hostname.

Comment: In my account summary, it says: "SMTP Service: Server Name: dedrelay.secureserver.net". However, when I check further back in my maillog, when I was using sendmail, I had dedrelay.where.secureserver.net. Here is a maillog snip: Nov  5 14:50:31 ip-192-0-2-0 sendmail[17665]: rA5LoVDo017665: to=example@yahoo.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30005, relay=dedrelay.where.secureserver.net. [nn.nn.nn.nn], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (lxqX1m00N2RKi1N01 mail accepted for delivery)

Comment: You reversed it. Did you not read the answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. I posted that comment before I saw your answer. Thank you very much. I have commented on your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such host as `secureserver.dedrelay.net`. You've gotten invalid information from GoDaddy or somewhere. Ask them to give you the correct hostname.

I would *guess* it will be `dedrelay.secureserver.net` and that you put it in backward. That *is* a valid host.

Comment: That was it Michael. I feel very stupid. Now it is able to find the host. However, I am still not able to connect to the host. I'm getting this now: Jan 29 15:30:11 ip-192-0-2-0 postfix/qmgr[28008]: D8B7BB97080: from=<info@example.com>, size=417, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 29 15:30:35 ip-192-0-2-0 postfix/smtp[28011]: connect to dedrelay.secureserver.net[nn.nn.nn.nn]:587: Connection timed out     Do you want me to accept your answer and ask a new question?

Comment: At this point, since you have the correct information in there now, you should contact GoDaddy.

Comment: Ugh they are so unhelpful. But thank you I will accept your answer and do that.